# Serializing and Validating Multiple Forms with a common Button and Validation Summary

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have two Forms on a view - each in a different tab. I have a Button and a Validation Summary placed outside the forms.

What I want to achieve is that, when a user clicks that button I want to validate both the forms and show the errors in the common Validation Summary. The first form contains some validations on the Model level (using Data Annotations) and some validations that are dynamically added using Jquery Validation plugin's rules. The second form contains validations that are all dynamically added using Jquery Validation plugin's rules. The reason for dynamically adding validation rules is that these validations are conditional - added and removed on some radio button selection, etc.

Here are portions of the chtml:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the following errors:")

<div class="tabbable">
        <ul id="ulTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>                
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                <form id="form1" action="#">
                   ... 
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab2">
                <form id="form2" action="#">
                   ... 
                </form>
            </div> 
        </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
            <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save as a Draft</button>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here portions of the script:

```
$(function () {
    SaveAsADraftButtonInitialization();
});

function SaveAsADraftButtonInitialization() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {

        var validator = $('#form1, #form2').validate();
        validator.form();

        var formSerializedData = $('#form1, #form2').serialize();

        if ($("#form1, #form2").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")',
                data: formSerializedData, 
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

1. The problem is that I am unable to see the error messages in the
   validation summary - e.g. Model level error messages and error messages for dynamically added validation rules.
2. The object that the validate() method returns only contains error messages for dynamically added rules and not Model level validation messages.

Comment: Why don't you use a single form?

Comment: 90% of the times users would be selecting options on the first tab that would keep the second tab hidden. Only 10% of the times the second tab would be shown and would then be required for users. Hence this is a requirement to keep the first tab short and simple and to move a section of the related fields to the second tab.